# WinZIP reports too many entries in "central directory"

Tags: zip, winzip

WinZip reports:

WinZip Error: too many entries in central directory according to end of central directory info.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs if 3rd-party ZIP packager attempts to create a ZIP package in older ZIP format which has limitation of maximum 65535 files (including empty folders), but the packager ignores this limitation and adds more files into the archive. When WinZIP finds this condition, it displays the above message.

WinZIP shows the above warning and continues its work in quirky way. For example, if there was 70535 files in the archive, 65535 is skipped and 5000 is extracted.

The solution is to ensure that the 3rd-party ZIP packager uses ZIP64 format which uses much higher limits than ZIP. But the easiest way to workaround the issue is to use packagers with their latest archive format (to avoid issues with mixing old ZIP and ZIP64 formats) and unpack using the same program:

- WinZIP → **.zipx** (not .zip)
- WinRAR → **.rar**
- 7-zip → **.7z**